# Is there any reason to run VACUUM followed immediately by VACUUM FULL?

Tags: postgresql

Because `VACUUM FULL` completely rewrites a table into a more compact form, it seems obvious that there is never any reason to run `VACUUM FULL` and then run `VACUUM`, because the second `VACUUM` wouldn't have any cleanup to do.

But could the reverse -- running `VACUUM` and then `VACUUM FULL` -- ever make sense?

One hypothesis might be that `VACUUM` makes the subsequent `VACUUM FULL` run faster. If this hypothesis is true, and if you are primarily concerned with limiting the time period of the exclusive lock that `VACUUM FULL` needs, then it could make sense to run the two commands sequentially.

Note that I'm guessing that this hypothesis is false, given that the `VACUUM FULL` to my understanding rewrites the entire table. But I'm interested in the general question.

I'm running 9.3.3 in case there are version-specific wrinkles.

Comment: Please upgrade from that version to 9.3.11, especially if you have replication set up.